# jQuery with a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<style type="text/css">
#DIV1, #DIV2, #DIV3 { display:none; }
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#saleselect').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val) {
            $('#DIV' + val).addClass("display:block;");
            $('#DIV' + val).slideDown();
        } else {
            $('#DIV' + val).addClass("display:none;");
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div style="position:absolute; z-index:1; right:140px; margin-top:-124px;">
<form>
<select id="saleselect" style="font-size:115%; padding:5px;">
  <option value="1">ONE</option>
  <option value="2">TWO</option>
  <option value="3">THREE</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>



<div id="DIV1">
<?php require "page1.php"; ?>
</div>

<div id="DIV2">
<?php require "page2.php"; ?>
</div>

<div id="DIV3">
<?php require "page3.php"; ?>
</div>
```

I need the `DIV` selected in the dropdown to show while hiding the other `DIV's` I also need to show `DIV1` as the default `DIV`

This code seems to show the DIV's in a stacked order. How do I only show the selected `DIV` and hide the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show `DIV1` as the default `div`, use the following:

```
$(function() {
  $("#DIV1").show();
  // ...
});
```

To hide all other `DIV`s but the one chosen in the dropdown menu, you can hide them all, and then just show the one that was selected:

```
$('#saleselect').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("[id^=DIV]").hide();
    $("#DIV" + val).addClass("display:block;").slideDown();
});
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QhjYC/)**.

Comment: Works great- thanks.. Why `[id^=DIV]`? And not just `[#DIV]` ?

Comment: @FA''''''''''''''''''''''': `[id^=DIV]` matches every element whose ID *starts with* `DIV`, thus it will catch DIV1, DIV2, and DIV3. It's called the attribute starts with selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/. Another option, is for you to add a common class to every div, say, "myClass". Then, to hide them all, you could use `$(".myClass")` instead.

Comment: Ah i see. How can I append the same function to link? Example say I have `<a href="option-1-link"></a>` Do i need to add an onClick function? If yes. How and where would that go? Thanks again.

Comment: @FA''''''''''''''''''''''': Yes, you'd need to add a `click` event handler. In that case, you'd want to show DIV1 if href is option-1-link, and DIV2 option-2-link?

Comment: Yes exactly.. However I don't need this functionality for this project. I was just curious of the implementation. Thanks again for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#DIV1').show();
});    

$('#saleselect').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#DIV1:visible, #DIV2:visible, #DIV3:visible').hide();
    $('#DIV' + val).slideDown();
});
```

You don't need `.addClass('display:block')` because `.slideDown()` does it.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eATcy/)?
I added a class to each `DIV` to make it easier to show/hide all at once.

Answer (score 0):

That could help [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMWaP/)

```
$(function() {
$('#saleselect').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val) {
        for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            if (val == i) {
                $('#DIV' + i).css("display", "block");
                $('#DIV' + i).slideDown();
            } else {
                $('#DIV' + i).css("display", "none");
            }
        }
    }
});
});
```

and also

```
#DIV1 {display: block;}
#DIV2, #DIV3 { display:none; }
```